# why use template Mat_ matrix

Tags: opencv

I read some `opencv` codes on using template `Mat_` matrix. Here they are:

```
Mat image = Mat:zeros(512,512,CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
        .....
    }
```

The `sampleMat` is `Mat sampleMat(1,2,CV_32FC1)`. Whey need using `(Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i)`?

Comment: less code to write and easier for non-opencv-experts to understand that it is a single precision float type. Afaik, if you do not convert back to general Mat type, using the template Mat_ allows to access .at method without giving the type again, allowing easier and less error prone access to the elements. But typically don't use it.

Comment: can you illustrate a little bit how the template approach results in simplified coding? Thanks!!

Comment: with a general Mat you have to use `.at<type>(row,col)` and you might get memory errors if you are trying to access with the wrong type. With the template Mat you can just access elements by `.at(row,col)` since the type is fixed and known.